# How to fix a website when css stops working

Tags: html, css

This is a continuation from my last question. I had made a slide show background on my site. When I added a js script it stopped my css from working. After asking for help and trying ideas nothing worked so i decided to redo everything. I tried to use css grid to put everything up but now it's even worse. I really need to figure this out because the site is for my wife's jewelry site.

Here is the html for the index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pinky's Pearls.com</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x=UA-comparable" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Pinky's Pearls is a website where one of a kind jewelry designed by Nichole <q>Nicki</q> can be seen and purchased">
    <meta name="keywords" content="jewelry, beads, bracelets, rings, pendants, necklaces, pearls, crystal">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="samuel jaycox">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="pictures/pinky.png">
  <script src="use.fontawesome.com/0c9491c5b9.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Start of background-->
<div id="background-container">
  <ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li>
      <span>Image 01</span>
      <div>
        <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/image_10.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <h3>Class</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
      <li>
        <span>Image 02</span>
        <div>
          <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/image_1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <h3>Rosary</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
      <li>
        <span>Image 03</span>
        <div>
          <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/image_2.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <h3>Sets</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Image 04</span>
        <div>
          <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/image_3.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <h3>Bracelets</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Image 05</span>
        <div>
          <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/PB0002.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <h3>Sophistication</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Image 06</span>
        <div>
          <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/necklace-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <h3>Necklace</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--end of background-->
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">
        <header>
          <?php include_once("templates/template_header.php"); ?>
        </header>
      </div>
        <div class="item2">
          <nav>
            <?php include_once("templates/template_navigation.php"); ?>
          </nav>
        </div>
      <div class="item3">
        <section class="one-third">
          <div class="icon-wrap">
           <img class="one-third-1" src="icons/necklace.png">
          </div>
          <h3>Necklaces</h3>
          <p class="one_third_script"></p>
        </section>
        <section class="one-third">
          <div class="icon-wrap">
           <img class="one-third-1" src="icons/bracelet.png">
          </div>
          <h3>Bracelets</h3>
          <p class="one_third_script"></p>
        </section>
        <section class="one-third">
          <div class="icon-wrap">
           <img class="one-third-1" src="icons/earrings.png">
          </div>
          <h3>Earrings</h3>
          <p class="one_third_script"></p>
        </section>
      </div>
    <div class="item4">
      <div class="clearfix-padding"></div>
      <section class="left-col">
        <p class="left-side">At Pinky's Pearls.com you will find some of my best jewelry creations. It is my goal to create beautiful jewelry that anyone can wear to any occasion such as a wedding, birthday or to be given as a gift. I really hope you enjoy the pieces I have created. </p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="item5">
      <section class="sidebar">
        <img class="sidebar-pic" src="pictures/aunts_necklace.png">
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix-padding"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item6">
      <footer>
            <div class="icon-text">
                <div class="icon-text-text">
                    <ul class="footer-nav">
                        <li><a href="tearms.php">Tearms and Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="shipping_info.php">Shipping Information</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-text-icon">
                <p class="email_text">Follow Me On</p>
                <div class="social-icon">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img class="social-icon" src="icons/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" height="45" width="45"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
      </footer>
      <footer class="second">
            <p>&copy; All Rights Reserved</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css: it is quite long:

```
@font-face  {
    src: url(fonts/BrockScript.ttf);
    font-family: brock;
}
@font-face  {
    font-family: giddy;
    src: url(fonts/GiddyupStd.otf);
}
*  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .item1 { grid-area: header; }
  .item2 { grid-area: menu; }
  .item3 { grid-area: main; }
  .item4 { grid-area: left}
  .item5 { grid-area: right; }
  .item6 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header header header header'
    'menu menu menu menu menu menu'
    'main main main main main main'
    'left left left left right right'
    'footer footer footer footer footer';
     grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
     grid-template-rows: 200px 100px 1500px 200px 150px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item4 {
 grid-column-start: 1;
 grid-column-end: 5;
}

#background-container  {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(pictures/gallary/pattern.png) repeat top left;
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 160px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: black;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { background-image: url(pictures/gallary/necklace-1.jpg) }
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/PB0002.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/image_3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/image_2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/image_1.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/image_10.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 100px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 50px }

  img.logo  {
    width: 1355px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 3PX solid black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  }

  #header  {
        background-color: pink;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
        border: 3px solid black;
  }
  h1.main_header  {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 800%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #main-navigation ul  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  #main-navigation ul li  {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 45px;
  }

  #main-navigation ul li a {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ff93ac;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: brock;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  }

  #main-navigation ul li a:hover  {
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid #ff93ac;
    color: pink;
  }

  .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 205px;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #main-navigation ul li:hover ul.submenu {
    display: block;
  }

  #main-navigation ul li:hover ul.submenu {
    display: block;
  }

  .one-third  {
    width: 33.333333%;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .icon-wrap  {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 125%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ff93ac;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-top: 23%;
    margin-bottom: 12%;
  }

  .icon-wrap img.one-third-1  {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 90px;
    color: black;
    padding: 17%;
  }

  .intro  {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
  }

  .intro::first-letter  {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .body  {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  .body::first-letter  {
    font-size: 150%;
    background-color: #ff93ac;
    border-radius: 125%
  }

  .ending-comment  {
    text-indent: 25px;
  }

  .dedication  {
    font-family: giddy;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

  #wrapper  {
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 1200px;
  }

  #main-body  {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  h3  {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 200%;
    line-height: 155%;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  h1  {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 300%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .left-col  {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5%;
  }

  .sidebar  {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1%;
  }

  .clearfix-padding  {
    clear: both;
    padding: 2%;
  }

  footer  {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ff93ac;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
    max-width: 1500px;
    min-width: 1500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .icon-text  {
    width: 33.333333%;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .icon-text-text  {
    float: left;
    padding: 2% 2% 0 2%;
  }

  .icon-text-icon  {
    width: 33.333333%;
    float: left;
  }

  .email_text  {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
  }

  div.social-icon  {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5%;
  }

  img.social-icon  {
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
  }

  .footer-nav  {
    text-align: right;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .footer-nav a  {
    font-size: 65%;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .footer-nav a:hover  {
    color: white;
  }

  footer.second  {
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    max-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
  }

  footer.second p  {
    padding: 5px 0 9px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ff93ac;
    font-size: 120%;
    line-height: 155%;
  }

  h2  {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
  form.contact fieldset {
    border: 4px solid #ff93ac;
      padding: 10px
  }
  form.contact legend  {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: brock;
    font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 150%;
      color: black;
      padding: 5px
  }
  form.contact {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      margin-top: 15px;
      line-height: 150%;
  }

  form.contact label {
    font-family: brock;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 150%;
      color: black;
  }

  form.contact label.fixwidth {
      display: block;
      width: 240px;
      float: left;
  }

  p.contact-form {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3%;
  }

  .button-area input {
      background: black;
      color: #ff93ac;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 2px solid pink;
  }

  .button-area {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 4px;
      background-color: black;
      margin-top: 3%;
      border: 4px solid pink;
  }

  .button {
    background-color: #ff93ac;
    font-family: brock;
    border: 3PX solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
  }

  h3.item  {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  }
```

I am also getting two background slide shows.
Can anyone see what I might be missing?

Comment: you're not telling what exactly isnt working

Comment: Pretty much nothing is working. Icons are not coming out the size My icon wraps don't appear. It is like everything stopped working.

Comment: @SamuelJaycox What have you tried so far? How isn't it working?

Comment: did you have problem about css grid rigth?

Comment: @Ismael Miguel I rewrote the entire css stylesheet, I rechecked the link from my pages to the sheet, Pretty much everything is not working, I somehow got 2 slideshws one on top of another.Special fnts not coming through, colors not showing up. prety much everything just stopped working.

Comment: @Udara Kasun   Yes having a problem with css grid. I never used css grid before. So grid is something new to me.

Comment: It is now affecting all my pages

Comment: Also i show you have added max min width. Then how to create responsive design like this? Did you have designe image as you tried to do?

Comment: Also did you have more pages Except this one?

Comment: Haven't done anything responsive as of yet. Want to get this fixed first. i have other pages and nothing works there either.

Comment: Share your design (image)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css"
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You have added five *footer* section. but you want to add **six footer section**

```
 grid-template-areas: "header header header header header header"
                      "menu menu menu menu menu menu" 
                      "main main main main main main"
                      "left left left left right right"
                      "footer footer footer footer footer footer";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the URL's you are trying to hit with CDNs

Could you try doing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="pictures/pinky.png">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0c9491c5b9.js"></script>
```

in place of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="pictures/pinky.png">
<script src="use.fontawesome.com/0c9491c5b9.js"></script>
```